# What is the term for the large ball shaped lights that are used to illuminate roads during construction?

Tags: word-requests

I see the large lights used for illumination at night, but they are shaped kind of like a round ball and powered with generators. Thank you.

Comment: バルーン投光器. You can buy one for $800 http://store.shopping.yahoo.co.jp/buymaruichi/2016-12h51.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think most people who are not in the construction industry just call them ライト (or something like 工事現場のライト).

If you really need a specific term for that purpose, you can use [投光器【とうこうき】](https://search.yahoo.co.jp/image/search?p=%E6%8A%95%E5%85%89%E5%99%A8&ei=UTF-8) or [作業灯【さぎょうとう】](https://search.yahoo.co.jp/image/search?p=%E4%BD%9C%E6%A5%AD%E7%81%AF&ei=UTF-8).